# Error submitting Codename One build, Parse4cn1 build command failure

Tags: codenameone, parse4cn1

I am using Codename One in Netbeans to develop my app and I cannot figure what is wrong with my build. My app uses the CN1 built html parser to extract data from the web and it works perfectly in the simulator but when I send it to the build I receive an error. Codename One suggested that I installed the parse4cn1 library incorrectly but I downloaded the CN1 Json library and the parse4cn1 library and then refreshed the CN1 libraries yet the error still shows. Thanks in advance.

Here is my error log: https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/618edd25-4dd4-49f4-9019-50312f0a49cc-1497973781424-error.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me a while to find out and probably needs to be fixed in the parse SDK itself. See [this](https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1/blob/master/native/ios/Integrating_Parse_iOS_SDK.md).

It seems that you need to add a build hint for parse to work. E.g. `ios.pods=Parse ~> 1.12.0`

I think that might be a mistake in the library as these need to be in the dependent properties of the lib and automatically included as I [explained here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/deprecations-simplified-cn1lib-installs-theme-layering.html).